# Trying to understand the restriction difference between the Open Graph "follow" and "like" actions

Tags: facebook-like, publish, facebook-opengraph

Looking at these 2 articles:
Like: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/465/

> You can publish stories to people who like your Open Graph Page the same way you write a Facebook post from your own wall. The stories appear in the News Feeds of people who have clicked the Like button on the Open Graph Page.
>
> You can also publish using our API. If you associate your Open Graph Page with a Facebook app using the fb:app_id meta tag, you can publish updates to the users who have liked your pages via the Graph API.

Follow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/follows/

> Similar to the ability to subscribe to a user's posts on Facebook, users can now follow other users' Open Graph activities from a specific app. For example, on a movie review site, users can follow their favorite movie reviewers. When a user follows another user in your app, all of the content published in your app by the publisher is eligible to be displayed in the follower's News Feed even if they are not Facebook friends (as long as the privacy on the actions published allows the follower to see the post):

It appears that in both cases you can create an Open Graph object that lives outside of facebook and either "follow" or "like" it. Using one example provided in the articles you could for example make that object be

> http//www.rottentomatoes.com/celebrity/tom_hanks/

If you decide to "like" Tom Hanks on the site, the page can publish news about Tom Hanks and they will show up in your News feed. (Assuming all permissions are ok, no worries there).
However if you decide to "follow" Tom Hanks on the site, if I understand correctly the requirements posted by facebook:

> In this case, the document returned by fetching the URL should have an fb:profile_id meta tag which represents the Facebook ID of the user:

```
<meta property="fb:profile_id" content="lbRw_a8fwsz8u7a_-iL5bCxjJ8w" />
```

> We recommend that the content of this field be the third_party_id of a user, which can be retrieved by adding ?fields=third_party_id to the request URL when retrieving the user's information, and described in the documentation for the Graph API User object.
>
> This tag is not required, and follow actions will succeed without it, though followers will not see activity in their News Feeds without this.

since the page lives outside of Facebook, it won't have a third_party_id and therefore if the site publishes news about Tom Hanks, you will not see that news appear in your News Feed.

Is there any reason why things behave like this?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Like, Follow publishes a single story initially. Follow however allows an app to build a "subscribe" relationship between two facebook users in the context of your app. Consider the example below which also illustrates how `third_party_id` is used to create such a relationship:

Lets say William followed Claudette in your app and that your app successfully published a follow action on facebook. Whether you provide Claudette's `third_party_id` or not, a story that William followed Claudette, will get published on William's News Feed.

However if Claudette's `third_party_id` is provided, then William will start getting stories about ALL of Claudette's actions published by your app. Now, thats pretty cool. But of course to do this, Facebook needs to know "who Claudette is" which is what `third_party_id` does.

To summarize, by not providing `third_party_id` the follow action gets shared on William's news feed and potentially to William's friends. But thats a one time thing. By providing the `third_party_id` you are extending the virality and ensuring a constant flow from Claudette to William for actions Claudette does on your app.